# Windows 7 installation stuck at drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I am installing Windows 7 on my computer, but it always gets stuck at the point where it asks for the drivers.

I have changed the BIOS settings to default, but it's not working.

I also tried with a flash drive by making it bootable, but it shows the same error.

I noticed that I am facing this problem after I connected my Lenovo A6000 phone to my PC.

[image]

If I simply start my system then it says "Reboot and select proper boot device"

Comment: Is the DVD scratched or dirty in any way?

Comment: If installing from home made CD/DVD disc, it is either a corrupt iso image or bad burn job.

Comment: I also tried with pendrive by making it bootable but shows same error.

Comment: Why connect your phone during OS installation?

Comment: Check your Hard Drive is set to AHCI mode in the BIOS

Comment: @jiggunjer - is on dot. Ashwini - You need to minimize stuff when installing Windows 7. Are you using Win 7 or Win 7 SP1? I faced similar issues due to hardware drama during Win 7 setup. 

http://superuser.com/a/996396/183467

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar - What is the model number or config of your machine - laptop or pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your valuable answers but what the person who repair computer  found is that my `hard disc is corrupted`, its not detectable by the computer .

Answer (score 0):

You should use a USB 2.0 port.
OR
In your BIOS Settings, set the USB 3.0 Configuration Mode to *Auto* or *Disabled*.

You can't use a USB 3.0 to install Windows 7.

Comment: What does it mean  USB 2.0 port ? I am using now CD for installing windows.

Comment: "I also tried with pendrive by making it bootable but shows same error."

You said you tried with pendrive. Try again. This time using a USB 2.0 port or disabling USB 3.0 it like I said.

Comment: There is no settings with name USB 2 or 3 , it just USB and I disabled both but still same error. I am booting with CD.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how connecting the phone can destroy the Windows 7 installation.
Some more detail may help about what you did and what happened and why you
cannot manage to boot with the Windows version that is already installed
on the computer, as well as your exact computer model.

It would also help to know where you got the Windows 7 CD/DVD and whether
it is a 32-bit or 64-bit installation, and whether your Windows serial
is OEM or Retail. Also whether the BIOS is set to UEFI mode or "Legacy".

In general, the error means the installation media is bad.
I suggest that you Download another ISO and burn to DVD or write to USB.
For more details see [Clean Reinstall - Factory OEM Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/219487-clean-reinstall-factory-oem-windows-7-a.html#post1839164).

Here is what [Microsoft advises](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2755139) :

> - Burn the installation DVD at a slower speed.
> - Use a better quality DVD to create the installation DVD.
> - Update the BIOS firmware for your DVD drive.
> - Use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe) to create a bootable USB flash drive, and then use the USB flash drive to install Windows.
>
> To troubleshoot this issue, use one of the following methods, as
>   appropriate for your situation:
>
> - Burn the installation DVD at a slower speed.
> - Use a better quality DVD to create the installation DVD.
> - Update the BIOS firmware for your DVD drive.
> - Use the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool to create a bootable USB flash drive, and then use the USB flash drive to install Windows.
>
> To troubleshoot this issue, use one of the following methods, as
>   appropriate for your situation:
>
> - Run the DVD on a different computer to determine whether the DVD works correctly.
> - Test your DVD drive by using an official Windows installation DVD.
> - Attach the ISO file to a virtual machine to check whether it is corrupted.
> - Run the DVD on a different computer to determine whether the DVD works correctly.
> - Test your DVD drive by using an official Windows installation DVD.
> - Attach the ISO file to a virtual machine to check whether it is corrupted.

Comment: Well I tried first with flash drive then CD then I tried another CD. My friend installed windows on his PC with the same CD. I have 64 bit configuration.

Comment: Please answer all the questions. The right place for that is in your post.

Comment: Actually I wrote what I knows . I don`t have idea about  "Windows serial is OEM or Retail. Also whether the BIOS is set to UEFI mode or "Legacy"."

But I have also tried by set BIOS setting default.

Comment: It would help at least to know (1) your computer model and BIOS version, (2) some more about the event that destroyed Windows, and (3) what happens when you try booting from the hard disk.

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar: The above is required for advancing with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Try inserting the lenovo a 6000 phone cd/dvd if you have it and search for the drivers on that cd/dvd
2. Download the drivers from [lenovo website](http://support.lenovo.com/hr/hr/products/phones/a-series/a6000)

During installation windows searches/discovers your hardware and you connected your phone. It this point it is not connected to internet yet so it won't find any driver (sometimes even when connected it doesn't find the drivers)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that has to do with Windows 7 not doing well during installation with excessive devices connected or attached to the system via USB or other channels such as serial or parallel ports.

So, firstly do not keep your phone connected when installing/ setting up Windows 7.

I faced tons of initial drama when installing Win 7. If I remember correctly, Win 7 vs Win 7 SP1 install, one of them had more drama.

Similar issues due to devices causing issues with Win 7.

- http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/140606-stuck-setup-preparing-your-computer-first-use.html
- http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=99106
- http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=99558#p651392
- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/bug-free-x61t-win7x64-bios-drivers-tv-system-update-apps.614934/

### What to do:

- Minimize the hardware - I disabled as much as possible in the BIOS.
- Let the setup install and everything complete and stabilize
- Also, if/ when stuck, boot into Safe Mode and then try things before a fresh reboot.
- See "Device Manager" in safe mode and maybe disable issue causing devices.

Comment: How can I open in safe mode ?

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar - Boot in Safe Mode
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/start-computer-safe-mode

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar 

- Do you know how to get into the BIOS? 
- Can you disable a bunch of devices in the BIOS? Do this after resetting it to default.

Answer (score -2):

i just had that problem. Switched the CD/DVD drive to an LG brand and managed to install Win7 without the error.

Comment: Sounds like you might have had a defective drive.  This doesn't seem like a general purpose solution.

Comment: Then what to do ?